# How to make ActiveRecord return timestamp as TimeWithZone in a minimal test case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I'm trying to come up with a minimal test case for ActiveRecord 4.0. What I have is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/awendt/9112672) which fails with this message:

```
  1) Failure:
BugTest#test_association_stuff [millisecond_resolution.rb:28]:
Expected: "ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone"
  Actual: "Time"
```

In a full Rails app, this does return `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. What I'm missing is the link between AS and AR so that the latter returns timestamps as `TimeWithZone`. I've already added

```
ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :local
ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_attributes = true
```

to no avail. I'm also aware of the [`lazy_load_hooks` in AS](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/activesupport/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb#L11-L16) but am note sure if they are applicable.

What am I missing here? Am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No time zone is set in your test. You have to set the time zone.

```
Time.zone = 'Berlin'
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html for more details.

Comment: Darn, I was sure I tried that as well. Anyway, it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright mate,

I've only got rails 4.0.0 on my computer, but a quick acking brought me to this:

```
# activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:39

# Report class name as 'Time' to thwart type checking.
def self.name
  'Time'
end
```

Hope that gets your nearer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! I changed the `.name` to `.to_s` to avoid that. Rails still claims `Customer.first.created_at.class.to_s` is `"ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone"` while the Ruby code from the gist reports `"Time"`. So unfortunately, that's not the answer :(